# Clicking "see full text" on a long chat reply shows message number without the arrow

Tags: bug, chat, reply

Earlier, I received a long chat reply, and the shortened version of the message shows:

[image: shortened version of chat reply]

But then, if I click "see full text", it shows the number of the message replied to:

[image: expanded version of chat reply with a colon then the ID number of the message being replied to]

It doesn't do this in the chat transcript, only in the room.

Comment: I think it has always done that...